# Compiling Fortran code

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran, gcc

I am trying to a compile f90 code using gcc with the gfortran package on ubuntu machine. Unfortunately, upon running the complier I keep getting undefined reference errors.

I am invoking the complier as follows:

```
gfortran -o gauss Guass1d.f90 linalg.f90
```

Alternatively, I have tried creating the object file for the linalg.f90 and then using the following:

```
gfortran -o guass Guass1d.f90 linalg.mod (tried with linalg.o as well)
```

Neither of these work. The codes are from a book located here https://sites.google.com/site/varga1kalmanbook/computer-codes/part-i/chapter-1/variational-method-shifted-gaussians (at the bottom of the page)

I am certain this is just an issue with how the code is being compiled by me but due to a lack of experience with fortran I cant put my finger on it.

Any assitance would be greatly appericiated!

Comment: Have you misspelled the term 'guass' consistently ?

Comment: You need to post the error messages that you get in order for anyone to be able to help you - we need to know what references are undefined.  Though as janneb says it is probably lapack.

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

```
$ gfortran -O2 -c linalg.f90
$ gfortran -O2 gauss_1d_c.f90 linalg.o -o gauss -llapack -lblas
```

So the reason is that linalg.f90 uses LAPACK, hence you need to link to LAPACK and BLAS.